# SQLite query not working with different android versions

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union

The following query works fine with *Android* ***4.3.1*** but not with ***2.3.7***. The result from the latter is ordered by `nameA` instead of `MAX(unix_time)`. It looks like, that the `ORDER BY` statement is completely ignored. I assume there is an older *SQLite* version shipped with ***2.3.7***, which doesn't get my query right. Is there another way to get the expected result?

```
String mQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT nameA FROM (
                 SELECT nameA, MAX(unix_time) FROM table GROUP BY nameA 
                 UNION 
                 SELECT nameB, MAX(unix_time) FROM table GROUP BY nameB 
                 ORDER BY MAX(unix_time) DESC
                 ) WHERE nameA <> ''";
```

**EDIT:** Changed my query based on the answer from Notulysses, works perfectly fine now.

```
String mQuery = "SELECT nameA FROM (
                 SELECT nameA, MAX(unix_time) AS time FROM table WHERE nameA <> '' GROUP BY nameA 
                 UNION 
                 SELECT nameB, MAX(unix_time) AS time FROM table WHERE nameB <> '' GROUP BY nameB 
                 ) ORDER BY time DESC";
```

Comment: Ah, I read it before that I dont need DISTINCT with UNION. Don't know why I kept it. After removing DISTINCT it works fine on both versions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the `ORDER BY` clause in your *inner* `SELECT` should not guarantee the order in the *outer* `SELECT` ( I mean that you can't trust this behavior). And if there is such a problem, why can't you give an alias to the `MAX(unix_time)` in the *inner* query and then `ORDER BY` the alias in the *outer* query?Also, you don't have to use `DISTINCT` as `UNION` already gives you result set without duplicates.